# Django - Bypass loading code in the apps.ready function when making migrations or migrating to the database

Tags: python, django

For starters, I have searched for this before with no luck to find something around this.

Background:

I have created an inventory application for work to help my team be able to quickly see stats around our IT infrastructure.  I have threads kicked off when the application loads to kick off some scraping functions.  That code works great, but it happens whenever I create and apply database migrations (manage.py makemigrations & manage.py migrate).

Goal:

I'd like to only kick off the scraping code when I'm issuing the runserver command (manage.py runserver).  This way, I don't have resources competing between the migration activities and the scraping activities.  It also often generates lots of errors because sometimes not all of the database models/fields exist in the database yet.

Ideas:

1. Modify the code in the django repository to introduce a flag that I can then check against before I have the scraping code run.  **Not recommended** This will get overwritten when I update django, and it won't persist between my dev server and prod server.
2. Find a way to check which command is being run with the manage.py, and introduce a check to only start scraping if that command is run. **Recommended** This stays in my codebase and can easily be moved around between dev and prod instances.

I'm open to other ideas to accomplish this.  If there's a different way to kick off the scraping activities upon starting the application, then that would likely work too.  The apps.ready function was the only thing I was able to find that would run something upon the application start.

Edit:
Here's what's inside the `apps.ready()`function:

```py
    def ready(self):
        set_default_database_items()
        if environment == "prod":
            from .threading.scraping import TimerScrape
            from .threading.keep_alive import KeepAliveThread
            TimerScrape()
            KeepAliveThread(1)
            KeepAliveThread(2)
```

Here's a look at the `TimerScrape()` thread:

```py
    def run(self):
        sleep(60)
        while True:
            idle = True
            vcenters = Vcenter.objects.all()
            connection.close()
            netapps = StorageSystem.objects.all()
            connection.close()
            rubriks = BackupSystem.objects.all()
            connection.close()
            current_time = datetime.now(timezone.utc)

            # get list of current threading and their names
            threads = enumerate()
            thread_list = []
            for thread in threads:
                thread_list.append(thread.name)

            # go through each vCenter and start scrape
            for vc in vcenters:
                thread_name = vc.name + "_thread"
                if thread_name not in thread_list:
                    if vc.last_updated is None:
                        self.vcscrape(vc.name, vc.user, vc.password)
                    elif vc.last_updated is not None:
                        time_difference = current_time - vc.last_updated
                        if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                            self.vcscrape(vc.name, vc.user, vc.password)
                        else:
                            print("vCenters: Too soon to update vCenter " + vc.name)
                else:
                    idle = False
                    print("vCenter " + vc.name + " update is in progress")

            # go through each NetApp and start scrape
            for cluster in netapps:
                thread_name = cluster.name + "_thread"
                if thread_name not in thread_list:
                    if cluster.last_updated is None:
                        self.netappscrape(cluster.name, cluster.user, cluster.password)
                    elif cluster.last_updated is not None:
                        time_difference = current_time - cluster.last_updated
                        if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                            self.netappscrape(cluster.name, cluster.user, cluster.password)
                        else:
                            print("Clusters: Too soon to update Cluster " + cluster.name)
                else:
                    idle = False
                    print("Cluster " + cluster.name + " update is in progress")

            # go through each Rubrik and start scrape
            for cluster in rubriks:
                thread_name = "backup_" + cluster.name + "_thread"
                if thread_name not in thread_list:
                    if cluster.last_updated is None:
                        self.rubrikscrape(cluster.name, cluster.user, cluster.password)
                    elif cluster.last_updated is not None:
                        time_difference = current_time - cluster.last_updated
                        if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                            self.rubrikscrape(cluster.name, cluster.user, cluster.password)
                        else:
                            print("Backups: Too soon to update Cluster " + cluster.name)
                else:
                    idle = False
                    print("Backups " + cluster.name + " update is in progress")

            if idle:
                platforms = Platform.objects.all()
                connection.close()
                applications = Application.objects.all()
                connection.close()
                functions = Function.objects.all()
                connection.close()
                regions = Region.objects.all()
                connection.close()
                sites = Site.objects.all()
                connection.close()
                environments = Environment.objects.all()
                connection.close()
                tag_reports = TagsReport.objects.all()
                connection.close()

                for obj in platforms:
                    thread_name = "Tag_report_" + "platform_" + obj.name + "_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.tagscrape(obj, "platform")
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.tagscrape(obj, "platform")
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update platform " + obj.name)

                for obj in applications:
                    thread_name = "Tag_report" + "application_" + obj.name + "_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.tagscrape(obj, "application")
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.tagscrape(obj, "application")
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update application " + obj.name)

                for obj in functions:
                    thread_name = "Tag_report" + "function_" + obj.name + "_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.tagscrape(obj, "function")
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.tagscrape(obj, "function")
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update function " + obj.name)

                for obj in regions:
                    thread_name = "Tag_report" + "region_" + obj.name + "_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.tagscrape(obj, "region")
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.tagscrape(obj, "region")
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update region " + obj.name)

                for obj in sites:
                    thread_name = "Tag_report" + "site_" + obj.name + "_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.tagscrape(obj, "site")
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.tagscrape(obj, "site")
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update site " + obj.name)

                for obj in environments:
                    thread_name = "Tag_report" + "environment_" + obj.name + "_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.tagscrape(obj, "environment")
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.tagscrape(obj, "environment")
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update environment " + obj.name)

                for obj in tag_reports:
                    thread_name = "Missing_tags_report_thread"
                    if thread_name not in thread_list:
                        if obj.last_updated is None:
                            self.missing_tag_scrape(obj)
                        elif obj.last_updated is not None:
                            time_difference = current_time - obj.last_updated
                            if time_difference.seconds > 14400:
                                self.missing_tag_scrape(obj)
                            else:
                                print("Too soon to update missing tags reports")
            sleep(900)
```

A little bit of explanation.  The idea is that every 15 minutes this thread will check to see if 4 hours have passed since the last recorded update for each of these items.  If so, and there is not a scraping thread running for the object, it will kick off a new scraping job to refresh the information into the database.

If no scrapes are running, then it will allow some reporting to run if it's been 4 hours since the last run.

This thread is self-contained, and, as I mentioned below in my answer, I was able to figure out that if I stuck a 60 second sleep timer in the start of the thread, I can avoid having the scrapes kick off when the `apps.ready()` function is loaded when the application is kicked off.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After thinking about this more, I found a simple solution by introducing a sleep timer at the start of the thread that manages the scraping function.  It allows me to run the makemigrations and migrate commands without having the scraping thread kick off immediately.

I also looked into using Apache with mod_wsgi, however both dev and prod instances are running on Windows, and mod_wsgi has difficulty running on Windows without some fiddling.  I might eventually transfer this over to a unix host, but that would involve some extra fiddling that I'd rather not do currently.

Answer (score 0):

The fact that you are trying to bypass code means that you have the code in the wrong place. Launching the scraper doesn't belong in `apps.ready` because you only need it to run in some situations, but not others.

Also, launching scraping code when you do `./manage.py runserver` sounds like a bad idea. You should only use `runserver` for development and not as an actual web service in a production environment. Instead you should deploy with a real web server such as Apache or Nginx.

You can launch the scraping code with a cron job or some other scheduler. If launching this scraping code is complex, then a bash script or management command is a great way to encapsulate what needs to be done.

Comment: The scaping code needs to run every time the application runs.  The entire idea is that if it's been 4 hours since the last time things were updated, it goes out and refreshes the data.  It's built in pure python using SDKs with the idea being that the only thing that's needed to do is run the application and then just let it be alone.

I'm not trying to bypass the apps.ready function, but seeing as how django loads up the application framework when migrations are done, the scraping part doesn't need to be run then since it's only going to be performing database activities.

Comment: @JimmyFort It sounds like you are using Django in an unintended way. Continuing down this path will only bring pain and suffering. You should ONLY use `runserver` for development purposes. It should NEVER be used to run the application. To run scraping code, you should use `cron` or a similar scheduler. Django isn't meant for this task.

Comment: @JimmyFort I suggest you learn about how a web app works. I've explained some of it here at a very high level: you should generally deploy a Django app using a real webserver like Apache or Nginx. If you are unfamiliar with these, now is a good time to learn. You will quickly see how you are trying to shove a round peg into a square hole.

Comment: Django isn't running a cron job.  The entire scraping code is self-contained in it's own classes and threads.  It contains its own scheduling and cron functions.  The entire idea is that the thread is kicked off when the application starts, and then it runs itself with NO additional input needed from the webserver.  The only thing that is being accomplished through Django is just kicking off the thread.

Comment: @JimmyFort I think I better understand what you mean. It still seems to me that launching the scraper threads from `apps.ready()` is the wrong solution to the problem. And it sounds like cron isn't quite what you need, either. Maybe you need an external script (bat, ps, or sh depending on the platform where this runs) that launches the django app and the scraper service.

Comment: I still disagree with that because the `apps.ready()` is intended to setup things that need to be run at application start.

I could setup another python file and have that call the application start, and the scraping thread independently, but for now I think adding a sleep timer delay to the scraping thread is adequate enough to keep it from kicking off when database activities are running.